# Vue JS real-time search on object's key/value pairs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Vue JS 2 as part of my Nuxt JS project to build a real-time search filter whereby a user can start typing and have results matched based on what they've typed.

I've got a search input, binded to the model of `applicantModalSearch` as a String, and an object held in `applicantModalData` with key/value pairs.

The data inside of `applicantModalData` is unknown, and not initially populated on page load, it's updated as part of the user selection from a `v-for` element, i.e: the user clicks a button to preview data in a modal, and the index item for that `v-for` item is added to `applicantModalData`

I'd like to be able to dynamically search for both keys, and the values, and not just the value and have results returned, right now my error is:

> this.applicantModalData.filter is not a function

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      applicantModalIsShown: false,
      applicantModalData: null,
      applicantModalSearch: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {

    /*
    ** Applicant modal data
    */
    toggleApplicantModal (applicant) {
      this.applicantModalData = applicant ?? null
      this.applicantModalIsShown = !this.applicantModalIsShown
    }

  },
  computed: {

    /*
    ** Filter applicant data for ease
    */
    filteredApplicantData () {
      if (this.applicantModalSearch) {
        return this.applicantModalData.filter((item) => {
          return this.applicantModalSearch.toLowerCase().split(' ').every(v => item.toLowerCase().includes(v))
        })
      } else {
        return this.applicantModalData
      }
    }

  }
}
```

An example object that I need to filter and return could be:

```js
{
  "_method": "POST",
  "honey_key": "test",
  "honey_version": null,
  "client_user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1",
  "application_source_url": "https://example.com/",
  "IsIframe": "1",
  "AppFirstName": "John",
  "AppLastName": "Doe"
}
```

So if I type in something like "John" into the search element (`applicantModalSearch`) I expect to get from my computed property:

```js
{
  "AppFirstName": "John",
}
```

or if I type into the search element "lastname" I expect to see:

```js
{
  "AppLastName": "Doe"
}
```

What am I missing in my code?

#### UPDATE

So after implementing:

```js
filteredApplicantData() {
  if (this.applicantModalSearch) {
    return Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(this.applicantModalData).filter(([key, value]) => {
        if (value == null) value = 'null'
        return this.applicantModalSearch
          .toLocaleLowerCase()
          .split(" ")
          .every(
            (word) =>
              key.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(word) ||
              value.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(word)
          );
      })
    );
  }
  return this.applicantModalData;
},
```

and adding more data, strangely the code will fail and only ever get to `client_user_agent_string` in the list *(I've added more data)*

is there a weird character maybe in the object?

#### FINAL UPDATE

Turns out that the following is needed to resolve and complete the function as part of the `Object.entries` part:

`if (value == null) value = 'null'`

Comment: On your update... it sounds like you're running into typical reactivity issues: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

Comment: @Terry Thanks Terry, so nothing strange in the client user agent string then causing it to break? How can I get around this issue?

Comment: If you're adding new key-value pairs to `this.applicantModalData`, use `Vue.set`: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Comment: `Vue.set` is not available as part of a Nuxt JS application. Furthermore, all 99 key/value pairs are available inside of `applicantModalData` at the point of search, but it's only ever getting to the fourth item which is the client user agent string, why would it fail at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed your logic for comparing the values, but applied them to both the key and value. I tested it on the example that you gave.

```
computed: {
    filteredApplicantData() {
      if (this.applicantModalSearch) {
        return Object.fromEntries(
          Object.entries(this.applicantModalData).filter(([key, value]) => {
            return this.applicantModalSearch
              .toLocaleLowerCase()
              .split(" ")
              .every(
                (word) =>
                  key.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(word) ||
                  value.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(word)
              );
          })
        );
      }
      return this.applicantModalData;
    },
  },
```

Some explanation: `Object.entries` returns an array of the given object's key-value pairs as an array [key, value]. This allows us to iterate/filter on that array and reconstruct the object with the opposite method `Object.fromEntries`.

Comment: That looks pretty good, except I'm getting an error with the Locale part: "Cannot read property 'toLocaleLowerCase' of null", are you missing a bracket somewhere?

Comment: I think there was a bracket missing at the end, I pasted the code again

Comment: Still getting the error `Cannot read property 'toLocaleLowerCase' of null`, and when I click the error in my console, it highlights the line `(word) =>` - I've checked that `applicantModalSearch` has a value, and it does, and that `applicantModalData` contains an object prior to running the code, and it does, something is missing?

Comment: I made a sandbox with the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-poincare-svozp?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: change 'toLocaleLowerCase' with 'toLowerCase' maybe, I think the auto-complete added the 'Locale' to my code

Comment: Okay, so strangely, if I type the letter `r` It begins to filter, but if I then remove everything and type the letter `h` it throws an error, even after changing the `toLocaleLowerCase` to `toLowerCase`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233282/discussion-between-ryan-h-and-catalin-hoha).